# Openshift postfix server not starting

Tags: docker, openshift, postfix-mta

I am installing postfix server from docker and then deploying it to openshift. On my local docker container postfix server starts fine and is able to send email but is failing on Openshift. 
Part of my Dockerfile:

```
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y postfix
RUN sed -i 's/relayhost.*/relayhost = <my.mail.host>/g' /etc/postfix/main.cf
RUN sed -i 's/myhostname.*/myhostname = <my.domain.name>/g' /etc/postfix/main.cf
RUN sed -i 's/smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd/2525      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd/g' /etc/postfix/master.cf
```

And then in entrypoint.sh I am restarting the server using:

```
/etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

This works fine on my local and I get test email. However on OS console it doesn't start. When I went into the terminal and tried starting the server there I am getting error:

```
postfix: error: to submit mail, use the Postfix sendmail command
postfix: fatal: the postfix command is reserved for the superuser
```

There are no other logs being created in
    /var/log/maillog

Any clue where should I look?

Comment: What about the rest of your Dockerfile? What you've posted doesn't indicate what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your docker image on docker locally, it runs as `root`.

This is a security issue and by default it is forbidden on OpenShift. Or to be more specific - it depends on your OpenShift cluster configuration if you can run something as `root` user.

I am not sure if you can run postfix without superuser privileges, so it might not be possible to run it in OpenShift without making your container a privileged one. You can try out this configuration: [OpenShift Origin: Enable dockerhub images that require root](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/manage_scc.html#enable-dockerhub-images-that-require-root)